# Logistic growth model of fox-wolf population in a forest

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

In a forest, the fox population grows at a rate of 10% per year, and the wolf population at a rate of 25% per year. The species compete for the same resources, and the forest can support 10,000 foxes or 6,000 wolves (carrying capacities). By taking F(t) and W(t) to be the fox and wolf populations at any time t, formulate a mathematical model with a differential equation.

I have developed the model to be

$\frac{dF(t)}{dt}=0.1F(t)\left[1-\frac{F(t)}{10000}-\frac{aW(t)}{6000}\right]$

$\frac{dW(t)}{dt}=0.25W(t)\left[1-\frac{W(t)}{6000}-\frac{bF(t)}{10000}\right]$

Is it correct? Now, how do we solve these two differential equations?

Comment: The equations look strange. When $a=b=1$ and we start with $F(0)=5000$, and $W(0)=3000$ there is zero growth for both despite the possibility that the forest could support a lot more. Before trying to solve such equations I would always solve them numerically in a small python program to see if the dynamics make any sense.

Comment: When I think of it: for $a=b=1$ the equations describe a dynamics where $F(t)$ and $W(t)$ grow if and only if the weighted average of foxes and wolves is below $100\%$. Probably makes sense.

Comment: They are coupled, nonlinear equations. You solve them numerically, with a computer.

Comment: [Relevant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations#Two_species).

Comment: These are [Bernoulli Differential Equation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliDifferentialEquation.html) and these often have no closed-form solutions. But you can solve them via using [Generalized Hypergeometric Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html).